# GRUB Minimal bash when booting

Tags: boot, grub2

After installing Ubuntu I have received this bash popup from GRUB and don't know how to fix it. I have given the output of the Boot info script from SourceFource to diagnose the problem. I do have access to the live CD and can do terminal commands if need be.

**Boot info script (info.txt):**

```
                    Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/grub/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/grub/mmx64.efi /efi/grub/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /tmp/BootInfo-IwLcdFvN/sdb1: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or mount point busy.

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT16
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sdb2 starts at sector 3672780. According to the info 
                       in the boot sector, sdb2 has 0 sectors.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /tmp/BootInfo-IwLcdFvN/sdb1: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or mount point busy.
mount: /tmp/BootInfo-IwLcdFvN/sdb2: /dev/sdb2 already mounted or mount point busy.

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,050,624 1,953,523,711 1,952,473,088 Data partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.6 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *              0     3,753,599     3,753,600   0 Empty
/dev/sdb2           3,672,780     3,677,451         4,672  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

/dev/sdb1 overlaps with /dev/sdb2

GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1               0     3,753,543     3,753,544 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sdb2       3,672,780     3,677,451         4,672 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        69C2-4564                              vfat       
/dev/sda2        4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        2018-04-26-18-43-51-00                 iso9660    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64
/dev/sdb2        044E-AC17                              vfat       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=C
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'GNU/Linux' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic root=UUID=4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2' {
    menuentry 'GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.15.0-23-generic' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-23-generic-advanced-4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-23-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic root=UUID=4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
    }
    menuentry 'GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.15.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-23-generic-recovery-4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-23-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic root=UUID=4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
    }
    menuentry 'GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-advanced-4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-recovery-4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4d1949f2-0e64-49fd-b1be-8c2f13f4bad2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=69C2-4564  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sdb

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  6c f1 37 00 00 00 00 00  37 27 19 2b 00 00 80 00  |l.7.....7'.+....|
000001c0  01 00 00 72 e0 fb 00 00  00 00 80 46 39 00 00 fe  |...r.......F9...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff cc 0a  38 00 40 12 00 00 00 00  |........8.@.....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sdb1

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  6c f1 37 00 00 00 00 00  37 27 19 2b 00 00 80 00  |l.7.....7'.+....|
000001c0  01 00 00 72 e0 fb 00 00  00 00 80 46 39 00 00 fe  |...r.......F9...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff cc 0a  38 00 40 12 00 00 00 00  |........8.@.....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-IwLcdFvN/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```